# How to find Scroll bar xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, javascript

I am working for a website automation testing. I need to scroll many times. How to find a Scroll bars`s Xpath in a browser ?

Comment: You do not need scroll bar's xpath, there are functions can do scrolling out of box for you, google them

Comment: I tried many but I need scroll bar`s xpath. Is it possible to have it ?

Comment: Why do you need to scroll? To get an element in view? What are you trying to test? With some more context we could give a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Scrollbars are part of the browser and not the HTML document. This means you cannot control them unless it isn't a real scrollbar (one that is created with HTML+JavaScript).

ScrollBars are operating system elements and cannot be driven by Selenium or WebDriver like other elements.

Possible ways to scroll with Selenium are:

**Scroll with JavaScript**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

This scrolls down 250 pixels for more idea's check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java

**Scroll to a known element with Actions**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id")); Actions
actions = new Actions(driver); actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

This scrolls to the element, for more idea's for scrolling to elements check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium

I think the Action way is preferred, but it needs an element.

**Trigger the real scrollbar**

If for some reason you really need to use the scrollbar like a real user would, because you have some action/event/trigger (I cannot come up with a good example). Then you could have a look at automation frameworks that can influence the operating system for example like: [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

This should be your last resort though, I would suspect the `window.scrollBy()` to fire most events you would like to test.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, scrollbars are part of the browser and not the HTML document.

But you can access the scrollbars by using visual web testing tools like [Kantu](https://kantu.io) or [Sikuli](http://sikulix.org). The Kantu Browser is is a wrapper for Chromium and thus has access to the scrollbar via its SCROLL page up/down command (pretty obvious command name).

Sikuli even has commands for things like scroll-wheel simulation (wheel(target, WHEEL_UP | WHEEL_DOWN, steps).

Answer (score 1):

**This code is for scrolling to the full height of the page. It will scroll down to the end of the page.**

```
 String jsCode1 = "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)";

 JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

 je.executeScript(jsCode1);
```

**This is for scrolling in upward direction.**

```
 String jsCode2 = "window.scrollBy(0, -1000)";

 je.executeScript(jsCode2);
```

Comment: Not sure how it answers the original question, but gave you a +1 vote so you have some points to comment :)